# Check valid URLs for Wistia

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I have found a code that I converts to UDF to check if the url of wistia is valid or not ..

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox CheckValidURL("https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w")
End Sub

Function CheckValidURL(sURL As String) As Boolean
Dim oXMLHTTP        As Object
Dim sResponseText   As String
Dim aScriptParts    As Variant

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.Send

sResponseText = oXMLHTTP.responseText
aScriptParts = Split(sResponseText, "<script", , vbTextCompare)
If UBound(aScriptParts) > 0 Then CheckValidURL = True
End Function
```

I have tested the UDF with several links and I got correct results but I am not sure of the UDF is correct or not
Can you advise me or improve that UDF?
Thanks advanced for help

Comment: As you don't have any issues/errors in your code, try posting this in code review site

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In fact I am searching for alternative solutions

Comment: what determines if valid? A 200 response code as shown below? Please provide valid and invalid urls

Comment: This is valid 'https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w' and you can add some letters at the end of the url to get the invalid link

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach assuming the page implementation remains the same.

Comment: you have provided 2 valid urls rather than one invalid and one valid

Comment: This is invalid `https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6wyh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could gain efficiency by creating the xhr object in the sub and pass to the function, and then only look at the response header `link` to differentiate

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim urls(), i As Long, xhr As Object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    urls = Array("https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6wyh", "https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w")
    For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
        MsgBox CheckValidURL(urls(i), xhr)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CheckValidURL(ByVal url As String, ByVal xhr As Object) As Boolean
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        CheckValidURL = Not .getResponseHeader("link") = vbNullString
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Alternatives:**

In the function test for the presence of an id which is only in the valid links, or a string (in the way you did)

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim urls(), i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"): Set html = New HTMLDocument
    urls = Array("https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6wyh", "https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w")
    For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
        MsgBox CheckValidURL(urls(i), xhr, html)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CheckValidURL(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal xhr As Object, ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Boolean
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    CheckValidURL = html.querySelectorAll("#wistia_video").Length > 0
End Function
```

---

Also using Instr works

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim urls(), i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    urls = Array("https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6wyh", "https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w")
    For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
        MsgBox CheckValidURL(urls(i), xhr)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CheckValidURL(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal xhr As Object) As Boolean
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        CheckValidURL = InStr(.responseText, "html") > 0
    End With     
End Function
```

---

**Re-write of yours:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim urls(), i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    urls = Array("https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6wyh", "https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w")
    For i = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
        MsgBox CheckValidURL(urls(i), xhr)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CheckValidURL(ByVal sURL As String, ByVal xhr As Object) As Boolean
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        CheckValidURL = UBound(Split(.responseText, "<script", , vbTextCompare)) > 0
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: As for the fist solution of xhr, I got False for both and when testing `?.getResponseHeader("Content-Encoding")` I got `br` instead of `identity`

Comment: I would expect the valid to be identity. Can you pastebin the result of .getAllResponseHeaders   for both indicating which should pass and which should fail?

Comment: Also, try: CheckValidURL = Not .getResponseHeader("link") = vbNullString

Comment: Yes it is working now with using 'link'. Thanks a lot for awesome help

Comment: That way is more efficient as you only ever deal with the header

Answer (score 0):

intead of

```
oXMLHTTP.responseText
```

you can use

```
oXMLHTTP.Status = 200
```

here is the list of status for xmlHttp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767625(v%3Dvs.85)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried two links one valid and one non-valid and both returns True !!!

Comment: In this case "invalid URL" still returns 200, just with a "not found" message.

Comment: Nice , you can use if "not found" then invalid

Comment: Can you show me this point of 'not found' How to implement it?

Comment: if oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 and sResponseText <> "not found" then
CheckValidURL  = true 
end if